# Nuxt3 "Never define ref() outside of <script setup>", then how?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

from nuxt 3 documentation,
https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/state-management
I'm told that I should never define ref outside script setup
since it will "be shared across all users visiting your website and can lead to memory leaks!"

I want to use vueuse's useBreakpoints,
https://vueuse.org/core/useBreakpoints/
I simply put them in composable and export,
and happily use them all across components.

but I see their type is **globalThis.Ref**
is it safe to use them as is,
or am I in big trouble as nuxt doc says?

```
// file: composables/useMedia.ts

import { breakpointsTailwind, useBreakpoints } from '@vueuse/core'

const breakpoints = useBreakpoints(breakpointsTailwind)
export const isDesktop = breakpoints.greaterOrEqual('lg')
export const isTablet = breakpoints.greaterOrEqual('sm') && breakpoints.smaller('lg')
export const isMobile = breakpoints.smaller('sm')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is closely related to vue's response system

you don't need to worry about memory leaks when using compiler tools like `nuxi`

however here another problem is that react system cannot determine the dependencies and when to unmount. if you want to declare once and use globally use `pinia` otherwise use this code:

```js
import { breakpointsTailwind, useBreakpoints } from '@vueuse/core'

export function useMedia() {
  const breakpoints = useBreakpoints(breakpointsTailwind)
  const isDesktop = breakpoints.greaterOrEqual('lg')
  const isTablet = breakpoints.greaterOrEqual('sm') && breakpoints.smaller('lg')
  const isMobile = breakpoints.smaller('sm')

  return { isDesktop, isTable, isMobile }
}
```

and use

```js
const { isDesktop } = useMedia()
```

> note: your code doesn't react when changing the values. if you need response use `computed`

Comment: arigatou sensei